# MySQL Encrypt returns true on wrong field with numbers as salt

Tags: mysql, encryption, passwords

I'm not totally sure how to describe this so the easiest way is with a test case. The running the following sql will return three rows on the select. My understanding of encrypt tells me that this shouldn't return any rows.

It only happens when the salt begins with two numbers.

Please also ignore the fact that encrypt is called how it is. Its a legacy app and I need to understand what is happening before making the change.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `user` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `test` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES
('user', '11');
INSERT INTO `test` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES
('user', '22');
INSERT INTO `test` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES
('user', '33');
INSERT INTO `test` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES
('user', 'aa');


SELECT *
FROM `test`
WHERE encrypt( 'user', test.pass )
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the `ENCRYPT` function. It returns a string, not a boolean value. Please better describe what you are trying to achieve with the WHERE clause.

Comment: As stated above, asked to ignore just that. Its a legacy app. I didn't write the code, just trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output without WHERE clause -

```
SELECT *, ENCRYPT('user', pass) FROM test;
+------+------+-----------------------+
| user | pass | ENCRYPT('user', pass) |
+------+------+-----------------------+
| user | 11   | 11VKs9AZ4WOfc         |
| user | 22   | 22QsW1gRCcd2I         |
| user | 33   | 33PLcxSqvhZnc         |
| user | aa   | aaBrLCcg4bKmQ         |
+------+------+-----------------------+
```

When you use WHERE clause, this values are converted to boolean; in your case value '11VKs9AZ4WOfc' is TRUE, but 'aaBrLCcg4bKmQ' is FALSE.

Here it is a small example that may explain this behavior -

```
SELECT 'A' = TRUE, '1' = TRUE;
+------------+------------+
| 'A' = TRUE | '1' = TRUE |
+------------+------------+
|          0 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

I think some of your values are cast as TRUE, and some as FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) is clearly mentioned

> If crypt() is not available on your system (as is the case with
>   Windows), ENCRYPT() always returns NULL.

so first check that `crypt()` is available or not

Comment: It seems that crypt() is available, because query returns three rows.